# How to show color corrected images after performing illumination estimation by deep learning in Python and Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am doing a supervised method of image color correction by deep learning in Python and Keras. I finished training my data and I predicted the values on the tested data. Now, **I would like to show some of these color corrected images from the dataset, so I can compare them visually with the original images.** I am stuck in a loop and I don't know how to solve this. Can someone help me with the code or some tips?

I already compared the numbers of predicted illumination and ground truth one, but I want to plot the pictures of how they look with the predicted illumination. I am using 3-fold cross-validation which makes it even harder.
I have more than 1000 images, but let's say I have just 12 for the sake of simplicity in numbers. I will train on 8 of them and test on 4 of them.

```
#this is the part where the training and testing is happening, images are loaded
#in xs variable and ground truth illumination is loaded in ys variable

for i in range (3):
    print('\nFold ',i)
    X_train = xs [folds[i]==0, :]
    X_test = xs [folds[i]==1, :]
    Y_train = ys [folds[i]==0, :]
    Y_test = np.zeros((4,3), dtype=np.uint8)

    model = None
    model = create_model()
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=8)

    Y_test = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=4)
    print("Predicted values for fold %d:" % i, Y_test)
    for y in Y_test[:]:
        predicted.append(y)
```

**This part of the code is functioning perfectly, what I don't know is how to plot or even just save each of these 12 images after the color correction with the predicted illumination.**

**EDIT: I have extracted the predicted values for each photo. How can I apply them to an image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to white-balance the color-casted images with the illuminant predicted from your model. Your prediction consists of 3 values (let's say [alpha, beta, ceta]) which are the correction gains that will be applied to each channel (Blue, Green, Red) of your color-casted images.

However, before you apply the correction gain, you need to perform gamma linearization on your images (further information is [here](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/gamma-correction.htm)).

Here are some sample codes to help you:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def gamma_decode(B_gamma, G_gamma, R_gamma):
    B_gamma = B_gamma/255
    G_gamma = G_gamma/255
    R_gamma = R_gamma/255 

    gamma = 1/2.2
    B_gamma_decode = 255*(B_gamma**(1/gamma)) 
    G_gamma_decode = 255*(G_gamma**(1/gamma))
    R_gamma_decode = 255*(R_gamma**(1/gamma))
    return (B_gamma_decode, G_gamma_decode, R_gamma_decode)


def gamma_encode(B_channel, G_channel, R_channel):
    B_channel = B_channel/255
    G_channel = G_channel/255
    R_channel = R_channel/255

    gamma = 1/2.2
    if np.all(B_channel <= 0):
        B_gamma_cor = (B_channel**(gamma + 0j))
        B_gamma_cor = 255*(abs(B_gamma_cor))
    else:
        B_gamma_cor = 255*(B_channel**gamma)

    if np.all(G_channel <= 0):
        G_gamma_cor = (G_channel**(gamma + 0j))
        G_gamma_cor = 255*(abs(G_gamma_cor))
    else:
        G_gamma_cor = 255*(G_channel**gamma)

    if np.all(R_channel <= 0):
        R_gamma_cor = (R_channel**(gamma + 0j))
        R_gamma_cor = 255*(abs(R_gamma_cor))
    else:
        R_gamma_cor = 255*(R_channel**gamma)

    return (B_gamma_cor, G_gamma_cor, R_gamma_cor)


def white_balance(img, pred_illum) 
   B_channel, G_channel, R_channel = cv2.split(img)
   alpha, beta, ceta = pred_illum

   #Gamma_decoding
   B_channel, G_channel, R_channel = gamma_decode(B_channel, G_channel, R_channel)

   #Correction
   B_cor = (alpha*B_channel)
   G_cor = (beta*G_channel)
   R_cor = (ceta*R_channel)

   #Gamma encoding
   B_cor, G_cor, R_cor = gamma_encode(B_cor, G_cor, R_cor)

   #Convert to uint8 to display
   B_cor = B_cor.astype(np.uint8)
   G_cor = G_cor.astype(np.uint8)
   R_cor = R_cor.astype(np.uint8)
   img_white_balanced = cv2.merge((B_cor, G_cor, R_cor))
   return img_white_balanced
```

Comment: Thank you for your input!
Yes, you got it right, I want to white-balance pictures with the predicted illumination.

Can you clarify how can I view the image after applying the predicted illumination?

Comment: @Tory Have you tried my code above? the img_white_balanced is what you are looking for. You can run cv2.imwrite('image_white_balanced.png', img_white_balance) for that purpose

Comment: @Pham, I tried your code and I also tried it with a bit of edits, but it doesn't show the picture properly. It is super noisy and with vivid colors only, so I am trying to figure out what is wrong. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you give me some of the color-casted pictures you're working on?